# Qt: how to dynamic change the position of other widget?

Tags: pyqt

Let's say I have a GUI:

[image]

When I click the `left` button, I expect the `object` would locate at left just like:

```
layout.addWidget(object)
layout.addStretch()
```

How can I dynamically change the position?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.btnPos = QPushButton('left')
        self.btnPos.clicked.connect(self.btnClick)

        self.btnLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QPushButton('object')
        self.btnLayout.addStretch()
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btnLayout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.btnPos)
        layout.addLayout(self.btnLayout)

    def btnClick(self, check=False):
        print('click')
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to appear on the *left*, if you're adding it to the end of a *vertical* layout? What is the purpose of this GUI? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. The purpose is that I want to dynamically change the position. Just like `self.btnPos.setStyleSheet('text-align: left')` can align the text to left. I want a similar solution. I want to dynamically make it appear on left or right. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, just take the widgets out of their current layouts, and put them in a horizontal layout instead of a vertical layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your btnClick function, you can set the Stretch parameter for each item in `self.btnLayout`. In this case you want to set the Stretch for the spacer on the left to 0 and the right spacer to 1:

```
def btnClick(self, check=False):
    print('click')
    # align button left
    self.btnLayout.setStretch(0,0)
    self.btnLayout.setStretch(1,1)
    self.btnLayout.setStretch(2,1)
    pass
```

For centering the button, set left and right spacers stretch to 1:

```
# button is centered
self.btnLayout.setStretch(0,1)
self.btnLayout.setStretch(1,1)
self.btnLayout.setStretch(2,1)
```

And to align button on right, set left spacer to 1, right spacer to zero:

```
# align button right
self.btnLayout.setStretch(0,1)
self.btnLayout.setStretch(1,1)
self.btnLayout.setStretch(2,0)
```